# "CASE WHEN" operator in "IN" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've stuck in an MS SQL SERVER 2012 Query.
What i want, is to write multiple values in "CASE" operator in "IN" statement of WHERE clause, see the following:

```
WHERE [CLIENT] IN (CASE WHEN T.[IS_PHYSICAL] THEN 2421, 2431 ELSE 2422, 2432 END)
```

The problem here is in 2421, 2431 - they cannot be separated with comma. 
is there any solution to write this in other way?
thanks.

Comment: can you please post the question properly with sample data

Comment: I don't think that `WHEN T.[IS_PHYSICAL] ` will work.  SQL Server wants a boolean expression.

Comment: you're right, but i just posted dummy data with the same logic, and i got the answer. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simpler if you don't use `case` in the `where` clause.  Something like this:

```
where (T.[IS_PHYSICAL] = 1 and [client] in (2421, 2431)) or
      (T.[IS_PHYSICAL] = 0 and [client] in (2422, 2432))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use AND / OR instead of a case expression.

```
WHERE (T.[IS_PHYSICAL] AND [CLIENT] IN (2421, 2431))
   OR (NOT T.[IS_PHYSICAL] AND [CLIENT] IN (2422, 2432))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could break it up into a combination of AND and OR.

```
WHERE ((T.[IS_PHYSICAL]=1 AND [CLIENT] IN (2421, 2431)) 
       OR (T.[IS_PHYSICAL]=0 AND [CLIENT] IN (2422, 2432)))
```